# Load template via ajax with ampersand-view.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, ampersand.js

Evening all

I'm having a play with ampersand.

Using the ampersand-cli demo project.

How would I load a template via ajax, for example on the info page

```
module.exports = PageView.extend({
    pageTitle: 'more info',
    template: function() {
        return 'my super markup via ajax;

    },

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least several ways to achieve this. The first one consists in extending the `render` function:

```
module.exports = PageView.extend({
  pageTitle: 'more info',
  render: function(){
    var self = this;
    doYourAjaxCall(function(template){//assuming your ajax call returns a string template
      self.renderWithTemplate(self, template);
    })

  }
});
```

Another way is to define the `initialize` like this:

```
initialize: function(template){
  this.template = template
}
```

Then you load your `templateString` via ajax, and then instantiate your view like this:

```
var view = new YourView(templateString)
```

Also you could manually assign `template` to the instantiated `view`, and then `render` it:

```
var view = new YourView()
view.template = templateString
view.render()
```

Comment: @magicspon, if it works and answers your question, don't forget to accept the answer ;) And if smth doesn't work (it can happen, though I think all the examples should work), please let me know so that I can edit the wrong part. Thanks!